# In octave, what gives with literal structs?

Tags: arrays, string, struct, octave

when I do this:

```
pedigree = struct('parents', [0,0;1,3;0,0]);
pedigree.names = {'Ira','James','Robin'};
```

I get a different thing to when I do this:

```
pedigree = struct('parents', [0,0;1,3;0,0], 'names', {'Ira','James','Robin'});
```

What are the two things, how are they different, is there a literal form for whatever is made by the first thing, and more generally, what are the words for whatever is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that a struct is also an array. When you create a struct using the `struct` command as in

```
pedigree = struct('parents', [0,0;1,3;0,0], 'names', {'Ira','James','Robin'});
```

the value of each should be a cell array, each element of a cell array being assigned. What this does is setting the matrix `[0 0; 1 3; 0 0]` to all `pedigree.parents`, and `Ira`, `James` and `Robin` to `pedigree(1).names`, `pedigree(2).names`, and `pedigree(3).names` respectively. To do what you want, just pass a cell array with a single element:

```
pedigree = struct ("parents", [0,0;1,3;0,0],
                   "names", {{'Ira','James','Robin'}});
```

Note how a cell array can include cell arrays in itself, so in this case you have a cell array with a single element (also a cell array).

Answer (score -1):

Quite a lot of enlightenment can be found here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Data-Containers.html#Data-Containers

Answer (score -1):

Quite a lot of enlightenment can be found here:

http://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/programatically-creating-a-struct/